# Turbolinks loads Javascript multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I'm using Turbolinks 2.5.3 and I have a script tag at the bottom of the home page.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert('hello');
  });
</script>
```

For every page on the site, I run the following JS:

```
Turbolinks.pagesCached(0);
```

If I visit the home page, the alert appears once. If I press the back button then forward button on my browser the home page will load, and now two alerts appear. If I repeat this process again, three alerts will appear.

Here's my question:

Why is Turbolinks caching the page when I explicitly told it not to. Does it have to do with Turbolinks transforming the document ready event listener? How do I fix this so it only loads once every time?

Comment: Why are you using `pagesCached(0)` on every page?

Answer (score 2):

use `turbolinks:load`

```
<script>
  $(document).on('turbolinks:load',function() {
    alert('hello');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the alert does not appear at all with this code.

Comment: This is accurate for turbolinks 5, but not for 2.5.3

Comment: turbolinks:load is deprecated along with turbolinks, what is it's replacement?

Answer (score 1):

Use this for on load instead

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
```

https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic#events

Comment: Sorry, this still causes the form to load more than once.

Comment: Nope, same result. The alert loads twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if (alert('hello')) {
    }
    else {
     alert('hello');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This is not a feasible solution as the `alert('hello')` is not actually used in my code. I've added it for simplicity's sake.